# Spring Boot and JPA project throws JDBC exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring Boot and Hibernate for my project and my database is MySql. I'm using annotation instead of JPA.
When I am calling the Rest api I am getting response like:

**Whitelabel Error Page**

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue May 17 11:32:13 CEST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
```

And here is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/db_myfme?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true

server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8


# HTTP encoding (HttpEncodingProperties)
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true

spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username= capfme@gmail.com
spring.mail.password= *******

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.smtp.socketFactory.port=587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class = javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable = true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback = false
```

Comment: am found this proposition `spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true` but am not sure:

Comment: can you look for the stacktrace of exception on your backend and paste it here by updating your question.

Comment: this error it's when i deployed my app(war file)in tomcat server(the error is displayed just in browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow: true
spring.datasource.validationQuery: SELECT 1
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.